# Travel the matrix from the botton row to a cell at the top row at minimum cost

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

Suppose I have an r x r matrix with numbers as each entry. I need to travel from any cell at the bottom row to a given cell at the top row such that the sum of the numbers encountered is minimum.
I can travel only one box at a time, straight up or diagonally left/right.
I know there are tonnes of solutions on the internet, but I would like to know what went wrong with mine. I have sat down with a pen and paper and worked out the whole algorithm myself, and I think it should work. However it only works for 3 by 3 matrices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int min2(int a,int b){
  if (a<=b) return a;
  else return b;
}
int min3(int a, int b, int c){
  int k = min2(a,b);
  if (k<=c) return k;
  else return c;
  }

int main(){
  int r,i,j;
  int myMatrix[10][10];
  int costMatrix[10][10];
  scanf("%d",&r);
  for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<r;j++){
       scanf("%d",&myMatrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for(j=0;j<r;j++)costMatrix[2][j]=myMatrix[2][j];
  
  for(i=r-2;i>=0;i--){
    for(j=0;j<r;j++){
      
      if(j==0){
        costMatrix[i][j]=myMatrix[i][j]+min2(costMatrix[i+1][j],costMatrix[i+1] 
        [j+1]);
        }
      else if(j==r-1){
        costMatrix[i][j]=myMatrix[i][j]+min2(costMatrix[i+1][j],costMatrix[i+1] 
        [j-1]);
      }
      else {
        costMatrix[i][j]=myMatrix[i][j]+min3(costMatrix[i+1][j-1],costMatrix[i+1] 
       [j],costMatrix[i+1][j+1]);
        }
     
    }
  }
  /*for(i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(j=0;j<r;j++){
       printf("%d ",costMatrix[i][j]);
       if(j==r-1)printf("\n");
    }
    
  }*/
  int x,y;
  while(1){scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
  printf("%d\n", costMatrix[x][y]);}
  
  return 0;
}
What's my mistake?
```

Comment: What makes you think that something "went wrong with mine"? Output? Crash? Hang?

Comment: <O/T> debugging tip: hardcode your matrices for now to avoid having to enter values each time you want to test.

Comment: You should also show us the input matrix you are using, and show the expected, and actual, outputs for that matrix.

Comment: @user3386109 My input was as follows:```3<br>4 5 8<br>9 1 2<br>3 2 3<br>0 2```. The output was `12 `while I expected it to be `7`. When the coordinates of the destination were (2,2) I expected the outpt to be `11 `and it came out to be `7`. In the case of (1,2) expected output:`8`, received output:`6`

Comment: @Yunnosch I have edited the question stating my problem.please have a look now.

Comment: I do not get the expected output. Please explain why that is the right solution. Please also explain what the current output would mean and why it is wrong.

Comment: I do not even get the sample input. I assume first single number is `r`, then 3x3 numbers for the maze. But no idea what the last three pairs of input numbers are. You need to explain more about the input format and about the logic of the program.

Comment: It might help to actually quote the assignment, instead of rewording it. That might provide a few missing details.

Comment: How can 2,2 be a destination in the top row? Which cell in the bottom row is the one you start at? Is that part of the input.

Comment: @Yunnosch I got my mistake, I was incorrectly assuming that the array index begins from the bottom left. I have fixed my code.

Comment: So, did you solve your problem? Then please create your own answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Not quite. I just tested it out for a 4 by 4 matrix and it doesn't work. It seems to work only for 3x3 matrices. I'll think about it for a while and post an answer if I find out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As long as you do not have an answer here, you can still edit the question to be cleaner.